# How to load parts of a huge gallery photos, on visitor's action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

In a *data.js* file, I have the paths of my gallery photos like below.

```
var PMalbum = [
    {
        src: "images/moleskineh.jpg",
        caption: "'moleskineh' - By Amir K (childofwar @ flickr)"
    },
    {
        src: "images/888.jpg",
        caption: "'888' - By doug.siefken (siefken @ flickr)"
    }
];
```

I have hundreds of photos and the gallery loads too slow. I thought of just showing a *x* number of photos by default, and if the visitor click on a "Show more" or he is at the bottom of the page, then the script will show more photos.

I had a case like this befor but with a XML file, and I solve it. The problem is how can I do it with this *js* file? What are my choices?

Comment: You could try lazyloading. Check google: https://www.google.nl/search?q=lazyload

Comment: @Johan Thank you for the link. So if I understand it correctly, the script works independent with what you have in page, or does it have to be linked with the page's scripts?

Comment: A typical lazyload script prepares all images but only loads the actual files when the user has them in his viewport. This should, in most cases, be independent of existing code.

Comment: @Johan Got it. I am trying it now